# FileNet Configuration Manager fails to connect to WebSphere Application Server

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-cpe

I have an issue with FileNet configuration manager connecting to WAS when configuring CPE. Details are below

OS : Windows 10 Enterprise (This is where CPE 5.5 is installed)

WAS : 8.5.5.13

WAS Java : 1.8_64_bundled

FN Config Details

[image]
I'm able to login to WAS console and the SOAP port is also correct.
Things that I tried,

- adding -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" in configmgr.ini of FileNet configuration manager
- Verified SSL configuration on WAS

  But noting seems to work. I see below error message on the FileNet configuration manager logs

  !ENTRY com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.engine 4 0 2018-06-27 15:45:09.289
          !MESSAGE An invalid profile path was specified. C:\IBM\FileNet\ContentEngine\tools\configure\profiles\dotnetclient does not contain any configuration information.
          !SESSION 2018-06-27 16:05:40.995 -----------------------------------------------
          eclipse.buildId=unknown
          java.fullversion=JRE 1.7.0 IBM J9 2.6 Windows 8 x86-32 20170718_357001 (JIT disabled, AOT disabled)
          J9VM - R26_Java726_SR10_20170718_1208_B357001
          GC   - R26_Java726_SR10_20170718_1208_B357001
          J9CL - 20170718_357001
          BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
          Framework arguments:  gui
          Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 gui

  !ENTRY com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce 4 0 2018-06-27 16:13:56.518
          !MESSAGE Connection error: The connection to the application server cannot be established. Ensure the application server is running and that the SOAP connector port and host name are correct.
          !STACK 0
          com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.engine.ConfigurationManagerException: Connection error: The connection to the application server cannot be established. Ensure the application server is running and that the SOAP connector port and host name are correct.
              at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.engine.jmx.JMXInvoker.invokeConnectMethodAndMethods(JMXInvoker.java:243)
              at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.engine.jmx.JMXInvoker.invokeConnectMethodAndMethod(JMXInvoker.java:142)
              at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.engine.jmx.WebSphereJMXInvoker.connect(WebSphereJMXInvoker.java:86)
              at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce.applicationserver.WebsphereApplicationServer$TestActivity.testWork(WebsphereApplicationServer.java:371)
              at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.engine.profile.EnvironmentTestActivity.test(EnvironmentTestActivity.java:64)
              at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.ui.wizards.NewProfileWizardPageGetProfileEnvironmentProps$7.widgetSelected(NewProfileWizardPageGetProfileEnvironmentProps.java:604)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
              at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
              at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
              at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce.handlers.ProfileNewHandler.execute(ProfileNewHandler.java:67)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
              at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
              at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
              at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
              at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
              at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
              at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
              at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
              at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.app.ce.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:86)
              at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
              at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
              at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
              at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
              at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
              at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
              at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
              at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
              at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
          Caused by: java.lang.Exception: The connection to the application server cannot be established. Ensure the application server is running and that the SOAP connector port and host name are correct.
              at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.utils.websphere.WebSphereJMXUtil.connect(WebSphereJMXUtil.java:227)
              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
              at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
              at com.ibm.ecm.configmgr.engine.jmx.JMXInvoker.invokeConnectMethodAndMethods(JMXInvoker.java:191)
              ... 45 more

*************************telenet response**************************
When did telenet and after a few seconds, I see the below error

```
HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 117 Connection: close <HTML><TITLE>408 - Request Timeout</TITLE><BODY><h1>408 Connection timed out while reading request</h1></BODY></HTML> Connection to host lost. C:\Windows\system32>
```

*****************************workaround*****************************
Ok once the profile is created and ran first steps, I disabled global security and restarted websphere. Configuration manager is able to connect to WAS now (looks like issue with security. I verified Quality of protection (QoP) settings 
 with ssl.client.properties and it was selected as TLSv2. Then I changed it to TSLv1.2 and modified ssl.client.properties also. Still it did not work) I will updated this topic later.

Comment: Check the Windows Firewall. Also, use telnet to connect to the SOAP port. But you probably have alreasy done that.

Comment: I did not check Firewall side. I did netstat on SOAP port and its listening. Again I don't have telnet access. May be I need to work with desktop team.

Comment: Try 'telnet localhost 8880', this will tell you if a connection is possible; netstat only shows connections and ports, but does not tell you if a connection actually is possible. Also, make sure the port is correct, if you have a deployment manager in webspere, the port would be 8879. Do you have more than one profile in websphere?

Answer (score 0):

Check default path Webshere.

> C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer
>
> C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\your_profile

VS

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\your_profile

Comment: Difference between 32-bit and 64-bit install?

Answer (score 0):

The Configuration Manager right now seems to support only older protocols. If you specify TLSv1 in WebSphere console, as opposed to TLSv1.2 for example, Test Connection will work. That will create you another problem though. Newer browsers don't support older protocols and you will not be able to open your WebSphere console in say, Firefox. On Windows, you can use your old but still included IE configured to use these older protocols - Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security -> Use * . You'll get your console back that way.